# Tracking package changes on CTAN

Tags: packages, ctan, update

If I download a [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org) package, I would like to receive email notifications whenever a change is made to that software. I know that I can automatically receive the updates themselves, [Updating Packages](https://www.tug.org/texlive/pkgupdate.html), however what I really would like is a notification stating which changes where made. If this is not possible, then an email notification notifying me whenever any changes are made.

Comment: See https://ctan.org/ctan-ann